# IE11 doesn't show google fonts (polish signs) properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I have problem with google fonts on my website. As You see on screenshot  one sign have another styles (polish signs). Seem's like problem shows only on Internet Explorer. Do You have any idea how to resolve this ?

[IE show this like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXNbT.jpg)

Off course I use font with "subset=latin-ext' :

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Może spróbuj wrzucić coś takiego w sekcje head

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-Ua-Compatibile" content="IE.edge,chrome=1">
</head>
```

Comment: Niestety nie pomogło :(

Comment: a spróbuj :<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet"> a w css    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;